# What is pure OSGi equvalent for Eclipse Platform.getBundle()

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

What is the pure OSGi equivalent to the following Eclipse platform call:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle( [bundle-id] ) -> Bundle

Comment: Not sure if it's exact equivalent ... http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundle(long)

Comment: My link got misinterpreted. Here it is again: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundle(long%29

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of [`getBundle(String symbolicName)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.html#getBundle(java.lang.String)), and plain OSGi does not have static helpers like this, because there may be more than one framework in a VM.

You can, as Amir points out, use [`getBundle(long id)`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundle%28long%29) to get a bundle if you know it's ID.

If you want the bundle with a given symbolic name, in the highest version, you can do something like (assuming you have a `BundleContext` available),

```
Bundle getBundle(BundleContext bundleContext, String symbolicName) {
    Bundle result = null;
    for (Bundle candidate : bundleContext.getBundles()) {
        if (candidate.getSymbolicName().equals(symbolicName)) {
            if (result == null || result.getVersion().compareTo(candidate.getVersion()) < 0) {
                result = candidate;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you don't have a `BundleContext` available for some reason (and I guess those will be rare cases), you can try to find one by using [FrameworkUtil](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkUtil.html),

```
FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext()
```

by which you can get the `Bundle` that loaded a given class, even for fragments.

Comment: You get a BundleContext in your Activator, and you should keep it around somehow. Certain OSGi DI solutions can also inject a BundleContext for you. Now, if you find yourself in 'client code', without a BundleContext in sight, you should wonder why you need to find other bundles in the first place.

Comment: The code in question is in a fragment that doesn't have the concept of an activator. The host bundle isn't OSGi-aware (besides the manifest file), so no activator there either. Locating other bundles is required for extensibility. Any other ideas? This is trivial with Platform.getBundle(), but I am trying to get this fragment to loose Eclipse dependency.

Comment: Well, there is a mechanism you can use; I'll update my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

In plain OSGi you can use [PackageAdmin service](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/PackageAdmin.html)
[`org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin.getBundles(String, String)`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/PackageAdmin.html#getBundles%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This class was deprecated: `Deprecated. This service has been replaced by the org.osgi.framework.wiring package.`

Answer (score -2):

Since OSGi 1.6 there exists also the method [BundleContext.getBundle(String)](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String%29), if you have already a BundleContext.

Comment: This method has always been there. The string is the location string which is determined at install time and is generally not known at development time.